# Convert WPF ArcSegment to 2 angle, center, radius

Tags: c#

конвертация DXF Arc в WPF ArcSegment представлена в следующем коде,

```
else if (entity is DXFLib.DXFArc)
            {
                DXFLib.DXFArc arc = (DXFLib.DXFArc)entity;

                Path path = new Path();
                path.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
                path.StrokeThickness = 1;

                System.Windows.Point endPoint = new System.Windows.Point(
                    (arc.Center.X.Value + Math.Cos(arc.EndAngle * Math.PI / 180) * arc.Radius) * scaleX,
                    (arc.Center.Y.Value + Math.Sin(arc.EndAngle * Math.PI / 180) * arc.Radius) * scaleY);

                System.Windows.Point startPoint = new System.Windows.Point(
                    (arc.Center.X.Value + Math.Cos(arc.StartAngle * Math.PI / 180) * arc.Radius) * scaleX,
                    (arc.Center.Y.Value + Math.Sin(arc.StartAngle * Math.PI / 180) * arc.Radius) * scaleY);

                ArcSegment arcSegment = new ArcSegment();
                double sweep = 0.0;
                if (arc.EndAngle < arc.StartAngle)
                    sweep = (360 + arc.EndAngle) - arc.StartAngle;
                else sweep = Math.Abs(arc.EndAngle - arc.StartAngle);

                arcSegment.IsLargeArc = sweep >= 180;
                arcSegment.Point = endPoint;
                arcSegment.Size = new System.Windows.Size(arc.Radius * scaleX, arc.Radius * scaleY);
                arcSegment.SweepDirection = arc.ExtrusionDirection.Z >= 0 ? SweepDirection.Clockwise : SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;

                PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
                PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
                pathFigure.StartPoint = startPoint;
                pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);
                geometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);

                path.Data = geometry;
                canvas.Children.Add(path);    
            }
        }
```

То есть здесь считывается с DXF файла все арки, они имеют 2 углы, радиус и центр, затем конвертируются в ArcSegment C# Wpf который имеет две точки и радиус. Вопрос в том, как сделать ровно наоборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по указанию только радиуса, видимо, подразумевается, что дуга принадлежит окружности а не эллипсу. По двум крайним точкам и радиусу можно построить две окружности с разными центрами, и **четыре** разные дуги. Для уточнения нужна ещё информация ([при задании ArcSegment она требуется](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.arcsegment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_ArcSegment__ctor_System_Windows_Point_System_Windows_Size_System_Double_System_Boolean_System_Windows_Media_SweepDirection_System_Boolean_)) о направлении дуги и признак `isLargeArc`.

Однако построить центры окружностей и найти углы можно.

Можно построить систему из двух квадратных уравнений для расстояний от точек до центра. Однако используем другой метод.

Центр лежит на серединном перпендикуляре к хорде дуги.

```
(dx, dy) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)           // вектор хорды
(mx, my) = ((x2+x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2)   // средняя точка
len = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)               // длина хорды
(px, py) = (-dy/len, dx/len)        // нормализованный перпендикулярный вектор
D = Sqrt(R^2 - len^2/4)             // дистанция от средней точки до центра окружности
(cx, cy) = (mx +- D * px, my +- D * py)   //два варианта центра окружности
```

Углы можно посчитать так:

```
an1 = atan2 (y1 - cy, x1 - cx)
an2 = atan2 (y2 - cy, x2 - cx)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили

Comment: В выражении для `my` я знак поправил некоторое время назад  - видели?

Comment: Видел большое спасибо